# Предложение, состоящее только из ФИО

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Может предложение состоять только из ФИО человека?
Например, *Иванов Иван Иванович*.
И если может, то какое есть конкретное правило?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение может состоять из любого количества слов, даже из одного.
В указанных ниже предложениях озвучиваются имена или фамилии (могут быть и отчества), при этом пропущены ответные слова "меня зовут" или "моё имя".
Такие предложения называются неполными.

*«Девушка, милая, как вас звать?» — «**Тома**.

Семьдесят вторая». Жду, дыханье затая…*
В. Высоцкий. Ноль семь

*Девушка растерялась.

— Еще раз повторите, как вас зовут?

— **Антохин Антон.***
М. Воробьев. Антон Антохин – друг Хеопса

*— Катера-то? — усмехнулся парень. — Это, старик, дело темное. Давай познакомимся сперва. **Югов Сергей**.

— **Горяев**, — представился Горяев и добавил: — **Юра**.*
В. Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора

> **Неполные предложения** — это предложения, в которых пропущен член предложения, необходимый для полноты строения и значения данного предложения.
> Пропущенные члены предложения могут восстанавливаться участниками общения из знания ситуации, о которой идёт речь в предложении. <...>
> Пропущенные члены предложения могут восстанавливаться из предыдущего контекста. Такие контекстуально неполные предложения очень частотны в диалогах.

[Неполные предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html)